# gdal_merge.py aligns incorrectly at the seam of two GeoTiffs

Tags: qgis, dem, gdal-merge

I am trying to merge four GeoTiffs from the National Elevation Dataset (EPSG: 4269) into a 2x2 DEM using gdal_merge.py.  For some reason, when it merges the upper two NED rasters, gdal produces a seam between the two of approx. 1 px that it fills with incorrect values (either 0 or some large negative number).  It seems like this is probably an alignment issue.  How can I eliminate this artifact?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you tell us which particular NED entries are causing the problem?

Comment: The two NED entries are for the NW and NE of San Francisco, file names `1-436482266\1-436482266.tif` and `2-486081568\2-486081568.tif`, which is the upper left and right quadrant from the following bounding box: `(-122.635, 37.645), (-122.279, 37.843)`.  There is no such issue with any of the other three seams.

Comment: Also, does the National Map Viewer no longer allow users to download geotiffs?  On April 4, I had no problem finding elevation data stored as geotiffs, but now can only manage to download .img files.